# Python click call command first then options

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

is there a way in Python Click library change the execution order?

I want to have `cli my_command --options --options`

now I have `cli --options --options my_command`

I don't want a command to be called at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of a click command is as follows:

```
command <options> subcommand <subcommand options>
```

I'm not sure how you would have two options with the same name for one command. However, the two '--options' options apply to the 'cli' command and not your 'my_command' command.

To achieve something like what you want:

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.option('--options/--not-options', default=False)
def cli(options):
    if options:
        click.echo("Recieved options")

@cli.command()
@click.option('--options/--not-options', default=False)
def my_command(options):
    if options:
        click.echo("Recieved options")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli(obj={})
```

To run this from the terminal (filename replaces the 'cli' command entrypoint):

```
python mytool.py --options my-command --options

>>Recieved options
>>Received options
```

Comment: Thank you, I've done the same way. I found a solution in Click documentation, but you also right